# Makefile problem

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, gcc, make

I was trying to make make command for a code in the remote computer.I found there is a problem and refuse to complete compiling. I need to get the logic of thinking on how to know the problem and solve it.

```
-bash-4.1$ vi Makefile 
-bash-4.1$ make
gfortran -cpp -O -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fbounds-check -mcmodel=medium -fopenmp fiscof2.f90 frames.f90 gdfxs.f90 -o fiscof2 -L. -lfis2 -L/home/gouda/lib/ -lfrNOX -lgdfr -lgdf 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdf
collect2: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました  (means:ld terminated with status 1)
make: *** [fiscof2] エラー 1  ( means: ERROR 1)
```

Comment: You can get output in English if you add `LANG=C` before a command. Like `LANG=C make`.

Answer (score 2):

The development package of library `gdf` (entered as an argument of `-l` linker option) could not be found in your environment. Install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdf-dev
```

Library package names are usually prefixed with `lib` and postfixed with `-dev`. Keep this in mind when a similar error appears.

Comment: gdf is found in my code and I already compile it before compiling my code/
I think there is another reason but I can't understand it

Comment: Have you installed it to a standard location (`/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`), so it’s available to the linker?

Comment: I compile it inside the remote computer. that mean inside the same path and I transfer the executable file to bin directory

Comment: This is probably not sufficient but `sudo make install` in the build directory should make the job. A library in Linux is a `*.so` file (or a set of them) and should be placed in one of the mentioned locations.

Comment: I just running everything according to specific sequence related to this code. the gdf library is not that one in sudo  ( I mean not general library, it is specific library) with my code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give you a specific advice without knowing the actual subject.